# Codeigniter changing y_axis for cropping

Tags: codeigniter

Does anyone know if it's possible to crop an image from the bottom in Codeigniter rather than the top? Or evenly crop top and bottom at the same time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set the y_axis and x_axis using

```
$config['x_axis'] = '100';
$config['y_axis'] = '40';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

$this->image_lib->crop();
```

but cropping is quite hard without a visual interface.

I imagine using an X/Y axis of '0' would crop from the bottom, but this is untested.